# Checking user input for numbers

Tags: c

In my main function, I have the following:

```
int main(){

    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    char name[100];

    printf("Create file with name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    fp = fopen(name, "w");
    printf("Enter data to be stored in the file: ");

    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
        if(isNumeric(ch)){
            putc(ch,fp);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Which creates a file and stores data *(by the user till the end of the input stream or Ctrl+Z)* in it with `getchar()`. I want to check if the supplied data has been numerical but I'm hitting a rock. I've read many topics and all answers suggest `isdigit()` but it doesn't validate numbers with a floating point. Here's my `isNumeric()` function:

```
int isNumeric (const char * s)
{
    if (s == NULL || *s == '\0' || isspace(*s))
      return 0;
    char * p;
    strtod (s, &p);
    return *p == '\0';
}
```

Comment: You need to change "char ch;" to "int ch;", because getchar() returns an int.

Comment: if you enter only one char, why you dont check (ch >='0' && ch <='9')

Comment: It still terminates the program once it reaches to the `while()` loop.

Comment: yes it will. because, you are sending char to your isNumeric function, that accepts char*

Comment: I changed it to `char *` but it's the same.

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned that `isdigit()` doesn't do the job for me.

Comment: Then count the decimals. And if you're really considering floating point you probably need to account for exponent-form as well.

Comment: Are you testing "all" input from a "single" line of input as being "numeric", or all input of all lines???  If the former, then I might suggest you use fgets() in combination with strtod() to test each line.

Comment: @TonyB, all input from all lines.

Comment: Why no one reads the manuals? You just ask the question without reading the manual, otherwise you would know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that `isNumeric` is designed to determine whether a *string of characters* is a valid number, but you're only giving `isNumeric` one character at a time.

To fix the problem, you need a `char` array that stores characters until you reach a point where the array should contain a complete number. Then check the array with `isNumeric`.

Comment: So basically I need to store the user supplied data into an array and then validate it through `isNumeric()`?

Comment: Yes, but the key point is there needs to be some way to determine when you've reached the end of a number. For example, if the input has one number per line, then the newline character `\n` indicates that you've reached the end of a number. Or the numbers might be separated by space characters or commas, in which case you would need to look for those to know when a number has ended.